# Most linked content is registration. How do i remove it?

Tags: google-search-console

In webmaster tools > links to your site, I have two links showing:

my homepage with 12 links and 
/index.php/component/users/?view=registration with 3077 links.

Not only is this the wrong registration page, its also highly weird that I have apparently so many links to the registration page. I had some dodgy user registrations in the past and wonder if this is connected.
How can I remove these links?

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove links to your website from someone else.

What you can do is 301 redirect it to another page if this is something that really bothers you.

Comment: Is there a way to track down where several thousand links to my registration page are coming from?

Comment: Webmaster tools > Traffic > Links to your site > Your most linked content > index.php/component/users/?view=registration

Comment: And you'll see the linking pages.